# Trying to reverse a string using arrays, not by "classic" method, but it doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reverse a string. "Write a JavaScript program to reverse a given string."
Here is my code:

```js
function reverse(string) {
    let string2;

    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let n = string.length-1;
        while(n != 0) {
            string2[n] = string[i];
            n--;
        }
    }
    alert(string2);
}

reverse("asdfgh");
```

Yeah, I know, this is the hard way, but I still want to know how to do it.
Error: cannot set property "5" of undefined

Comment: `string2` is never initialized. Also, you don't need that `for` loop.

Comment: string2 is undefined so any [index] access will fail.

Comment: @4castle, I know that you don't really need that, but I've tried to do it this way.

Comment: @AlexK. I know, but I didn't know how to define it to an empty variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need that `for-loop`, use the `while-loop`.
- Initialize the array `string2 = []`
- Use the function `push()` to add chars.

```js
function reverse(string) {
  let string2 = [];
  let n = string.length - 1;
  while (n >= 0) {
    string2.push(string[n]);
    n--;
  }

  console.log(string2.join(''));
}
reverse("asdfgh");
```

Comment: It could even be done in one-line, using split,reverse,join, but I tried to do it this way, with for, that's why I used it. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @f0rta yes, you can use the built-in functions, but this way you can learn more about JS.  You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever way you are trying to achieve this might lead you in higher time complexity. You just need one for loop to achieve this.

```js
function reverse(string) {
  let string2 = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= string.length; i++) {
    string2 += string[string.length - i];
  }
  alert(string2);
}
reverse("asdfgh");
```

Other simpler solution could be:

```js
function reverse(string) {
  alert(Array.from(string).reverse().join(""));
}
reverse("asdfgh");
```

Comment: I know. Just tried to do it that way and it just didn't work and I had to figure out why. I got that it string2 wasn't initialised, but I didn't know how to initialise it to an empty variable. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is that you never initialize the value of string2, so it is undefined. In your loop, you are trying to access string2[5], which throws the error.

You don't need multiple loops. You can do this with one loop, if you are trying to do it yourself that is, with something like the following.

```
function reverse(val) {
  var reversed = '';

  for (var i = val.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed += val[i];
  }

  return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't really know how to define it to an empty array, now I do!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick-and-dirty (i.e., not the best) example that simply iterates over the original string in reverse order appending the original string's characters to a new string.

```
function reverse(orig) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = orig.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    result = result + orig[i];
  }

  return result; 
}

// usage:
reverse("abcde");  // edcba
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
function reverse(text) {
  return [...text].reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverse('Hello World'));
```

Comment: I already solved it from the other answers. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Legacy proof equivalent (<ES6) just in case: `return text.split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score -2):

Oneliner:

```
function reverse(string) {
    return string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: This does not explain the problem with the OP's code.

Comment: I know. I tried to do it this way and I couldn't figure out how.